# $a+b\sqrt{3}$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $a+b\sqrt{3}$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I have tried to find a limit point of the set which is not in the set. But I am unable to find it. My observations:

- all integers are in set
- if x, y belong to set, then so does $\alpha x+\beta y$ where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Z}$.

But not able to proceed further.

Comment: Hint: if $x$ is irrational, then for any real number $y$, you can find integers $n$ such that $nx - y$ is arbitrarily close to an integer (you can try proving this yourself). Use this to prove that the closure of $\{a + b \sqrt{3} : a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If you were assigned this problem, then there should have been some material before this point that will help in solving it.  But we do not know what that was.

Comment: What does "closed" mean in this context ? Since it is not topology, a closed set cannot be meant.

Comment: Hint: $a+b\sqrt3\ne\sqrt2$ (because $\sqrt3=\dfrac{2-a^2-3b^2}{2ab}$ is impossible.)

Comment: Note:  $1-(\sqrt3-1)+(\sqrt3-1)^2-(\sqrt3-1)^3+\cdots=\dfrac{\sqrt3}3$

Comment: @ConnorHarris so you mean I can find an integer such that on multiply by $\sqrt 3$ to get any required sequence of digits after  the decimal. But i don;t know how to prove this..

Comment: @YvesDaoust and J. W. Tanner I cant figure out how to use these facts to proceed!

Comment: Isn't $\dfrac{\sqrt3}3$ then a limit point of the set that is not in the set?

Comment: Your question asks whether a certain number is closed. What you really want to know is whether the set $\{a + b\sqrt3 \mid  a,b \in \mathbb Z\}$ is closed.

Answer (score 3):

You wanted to find a limit point of the set $S=\{a+b\sqrt3|a,b\in\mathbb Z\}$ that is not in $S$.

Note that the partial sums of the series $1-(\sqrt3-1)+(\sqrt3-1)^2-(\sqrt3-1)^3+\cdots$ are in $S$,

but the limit $\dfrac1{1+\sqrt3-1}=\dfrac1{\sqrt3}=\dfrac13\sqrt3\in\mathbb R$ is not in $S$, since $\dfrac13\not\in\mathbb Z$.